# Deploying iOS app to App Store with un-enrolled account that belongs to an enrolled team

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm working as a freelance iOS dev for an app and I have recently lost my enrollment in the developer program. However, this un-enrolled account is also an admin for an enterprise account that is currently enrolled to the program.

Whenever I try to go to iTunnes Connect or to archive the app it doesn't work because apparently my account is not enrolled, but my guess was that since the team is enrolled there wouldn't be a problem.

On Xcode I'm signing the app with my account, it says it's a personal team but as I said, the account is admin for another team.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: This sounds like you should ask the AppStore Support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no.

Enterprise accounts cannot submit apps to the App Store. You will need to use a non-enterprise account to do this. A personal team on the enterprise account also has that limitation.

Comment: So basically the one uploading the app has to be enrolled, even if the team they belong to is enrolled but the specific personal account is not?

Comment: Yes, what matters is the team where the developer certificate was created.